# Is it free to send International sms using mobicents smscgateway?

Tags: sms-gateway, mobicents

I just heard of mobicents smscgateway. I just want to know if it can send free international sms ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it depends on the provider you use to support the SMS delivery to the subscribers. The provider is responsible for deal with charges related to the used services, it is not a matter directly related to the SMSC Gateway.

For more info about SMSC Gateway, please see the links bellow:

http://www.telestax.com/introduction-to-telscale-smsc-gateway/

https://github.com/mobicents/smscgateway